# Should we actively migrate or move emacs questions from other StackExchange sites to the new Emacs Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration, site-crossover

Should we actively migrate or move emacs questions from other StackExchange sites to the new Emacs Stack Exchange?

I don't know if there is existing policy or not about this, but I couldn't find it on either meta or area51 or the FAQs. So I'm curious if we should actively search for questions that are on other SE sites and copy or move them here?

If so, should we do that now or only after the beta period has ended?

Also, if we should migrate and/or move questions, should we only move questions that were marked as off-topic and/or got bad answers in other SE sites or should we try to move them all?

Answer (score 9):

No, please; [**Respect the community – your own, and others’**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)

We are *not* going to be building the content of this site by migrating posts away from elsewhere.

We have no basis to take away another site's content unless it was off topic for that site.  Consider that users on Stack Overflow or wherever **may not *want* their content taken away** like that. You would be be taking away the reputation earned on those sites, and in most cases, stripping away the ownership of those posts when users do not have corresponding accounts here.

Also (before it is suggested), **please do NOT solicit users on other sites** to ask their Emacs questions here by leaving comments to that effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think we should postpone this question until after the beta period. Makes no sense to migrate posts if we don't make it out of beta.